# Apply batch file to work in all files in a folder/path, actually work in the file setted only

Tags: file, csv, batch-file, file-conversion

I need to apply a batch file to all files in the same folder, actually this batch file work for the file setted only.

This batch file convert the csv with separated lines, remove a problem of format visible via notepad of windows where all lines of csv are merged, after i run this batch file it separe all lines in csv, i need to apply this function to all csv saved in the folder without having to indicate all the names of the individual CSVs

This is the code actually it work only for mylist.csv, i need to adapt to work in all files csv saved in the same folder.

The name of csv change periodically and it's hard everytime edit the batch file with new csv names, i prefer a solution to apply the function to all csv saved in same folder (path).

Batch file create a new files with correct format and after delete old file and rename the new file.

```
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::::::::::: Database To Convert :::::::::::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

set DatabaseName=mylist.csv
set DatabasePath=D:\Programmi Installati\csv\

FIND /V "" < "%DatabasePath%%DatabaseName%" > "%DatabasePath%%DatabaseName%.new"
DEL "%DatabasePath%%DatabaseName%"
REN "%DatabasePath%%DatabaseName%.new" "%DatabaseName%"
```

Comment: I answered this however I deleted it because not attempt has been made on your end. Use subroutines, call your subroutine, this should include a for loop and the filenames can be handled easily with wildcards.

Comment: use a [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop to iterate over the files. Be sure to implement something to avoid reprocessing already processed files (like a different extension or putting the results in another folder)

Comment: I do not find any solution, it's a very hard question this i search a solution